# AWS Cloudwatch set batch_size and batch_limit options Cloudwatch constructor in node js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there a way to set AWS Cloudwatch batch_size and batch_limit options in the Cloudwatch constructor?

I have been trying to do something like this

```yaml
var cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch(
                   batch_size: 1000,
                   batch_count: 10
                 )
```

This is because I get the exception that the logs exceed the limit.
InvalidParameterException: Upload too large: 1049972 bytes exceeds limit of 1048576

Comment: Can you provide more details on what triggers the logging? What type of information are you trying to send to cloudwatch?

Comment: What lines of code generate this error? What logs are being uploaded?